# How to implement the btIDebugDraw interface of Bullet in OpenGL 4.0

Tags: opengl-3, bulletphysics

Bullet has an implementation of the btIDebugDraw interface in older OpenGL which is used to draw the physics world for debugging. The interface is like this :

```
class GLDebugDrawer : public btIDebugDraw
{
int m_debugMode;

public:

GLDebugDrawer();
virtual ~GLDebugDrawer(); 

virtual void    drawLine(const btVector3& from,const btVector3& to,const btVector3&  fromColor, const btVector3& toColor);

virtual void    drawLine(const btVector3& from,const btVector3& to,const btVector3& color);

virtual void    drawSphere (const btVector3& p, btScalar radius, const btVector3& color);

virtual void    drawTriangle(const btVector3& a,const btVector3& b,const btVector3& c,const btVector3& color,btScalar alpha);

virtual void    drawContactPoint(const btVector3& PointOnB,const btVector3& normalOnB,btScalar distance,int lifeTime,const btVector3& color);

virtual void    reportErrorWarning(const char* warningString);

virtual void    draw3dText(const btVector3& location,const char* textString);

virtual void    setDebugMode(int debugMode);

virtual int     getDebugMode() const { return m_debugMode;}

};
```

The OpenGL 1.1 implementation works in immediate mode sending vertices down to the GPU at every function call. eg. here is drawLine()

```
void    GLDebugDrawer::drawLine(const btVector3& from,const btVector3& to,const btVector3& fromColor, const btVector3& toColor)
{

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(fromColor.getX(), fromColor.getY(), fromColor.getZ());
        glVertex3d(from.getX(), from.getY(), from.getZ());
        glColor3f(toColor.getX(), toColor.getY(), toColor.getZ());
        glVertex3d(to.getX(), to.getY(), to.getZ());
    glEnd();
}
```

To convert this into OpenGL 4.0, I am thinking of using a Vertex Array Object defined as a member of this class, say mVAO and the VBOs will also be members. I will setup the VAO in the ctor of GLDebugDrawer and then generate and send vertices to the VBO as well as render it within drawLine()

```
drawLine()
{
    // Update buffers
    // Bind and render the buffer
}
```

But since I ll be sending vertices everytime drawLine() gets called, it seems I am not using the  power of VAO but instead simulating immediate mode rather badly!

What would be a better way to implement a line drawing function in this interface whose vertices can *change* in every call ?

I want to use this code in my android app later to check my physics, so I am rewriting the interface in OpenGL 4.0 which I assume will be easier to convert to openGLES 2.0 .

I was thinking of recording the vertices in a vector at every drawLine() call and then updating the VBO after all of Bullet's calls to the btIDebugDraw functions are complete. Then I would not need to send pairs of vertices intermittently to the GPU as Bullet calls the btIDebugDraw functions.

I have got some information here about managing vertex data so far : 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html

Comment: There's really no good way to do this where they give you the vertices one at a time, and they change each frame. It's just a debug function anyway, so I'd just continue simulating immediate mode like you are doing, and turn off the debug mode except for when you need it for debug.

Comment: Thanks, then I ll try my best to optimize it by gathering up the points in a data structure and doing just 1 VBO update call.

Comment: @safe_malloc I am also trying to implement this in OpenGL 4.4. In my "drawLine" function I collect all the **from** and **to** vertices in a std::vector. Then pass that vector to a VBO and in my rendering function I draw using GL_LINES. Before next stepSimulation() I clear my vector structure and VBO.

But my code seems like it is not drawing as it should. Have you made your code public somewhere like GitHub etc. That would be helpful.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/rapid-concepts/source/browse/trunk/simviewer/bulletdebugdrawer.cpp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not immediately draw on `drawLine()`. :)
Instead push the Vertices/Colors into a buffer in Host/RAM.

After the call to `dynamicsWorld->debugDrawWorld()`, you know that your `DebugDrawer` got all the lines for the frame, so you can do:

1. update the VBOs once
2. `glDraw ...`
3. clear the Host Buffer

Comment: Thanks, yes thats exactly what I do now. So the VBOs get updated on every call to debugDrawWorld() or per frame I guess. I can probably also reduce the amount of data sent to the VBO by doing a vertex compare to find the changed vertices and send only those.